# What are the dangers of swapping memory out

Tags: c, linux, posix

While browsing codes of lightdm-gtk-greeter I found this part especially interesting for me:

```
/* Prevent memory from being swapped out, as we are dealing with passwords */
mlockall (MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE);
```

What are the dangers of swapping memory when dealing with passwords?

Comment: Swapping out the memory might of course store the unencrypted passwords in the swap file.

Comment: does anyone have access to swap file?

Comment: The administrator of the computer might read the file. Or anyone else hacking the system...

Comment: Of course, the administrator or anyone hacking the system could *also* read the memory directly and find the password, so this probably isn't to solve that problem. More likely, it's to prevent the case where the password gets put into the swap file and then the system is *turned off*, so that the contents of the swap file could be dumped out of the disk without any security measures in place.